# "Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression" Got error after upgrade to ef core . 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

My project was .net core 2.2 and upgraded to .net 5 and EF 5.0
My last query was

```
 public IList<Group<String, UsefullLink>> GetAllGroupActive()
 {
     return (from b in _db.UsefullLinks
             group b by b.UseFullLinkType.Name into g
             select new Univer.Business.Model.Group<string, UsefullLink> 
             { 
                 Key = g.Key, 
                 Values = g 
             }).ToList();        
 }
```

My Models

```
public class UsefullLink
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public int LinkTypeId { get; set; }

    public LinkType LinkType { get; set; }
  
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    
...       
 
    public string Description { get; set; }
  

    public int UseFullLinkTypeId { get; set; }
   
    public UseFullLinkType UseFullLinkType { get; set; }
}

public class UseFullLinkType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
  
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime InputDate { get; set; }

    public int Priority { get; set; }

   public ICollection<UsefullLink> UsefullLinks { get; set; }
}
```

my view

```
@using Univer.Business.Model
@model List<Group<string, Univer.Model.UsefullLink>>
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "ServiceTebbedTable";
}
<div class="container">
<div class="row UsefullLink ">

    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header"> <a asp-action="ServiseTable" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="">service table</a></div>
        <ul class="row" style="margin-left:25px ;margin-right:25px;">

            @foreach (var group in Model)
            {
                <li class="row col-md-12" id="cut-diamond"> @group.Key</li>
                <li class="m-1"></li>
                foreach (var link in group.Values)
                {
                    <li class="col-md-4 mt-2  justify-content-center">
                        @if (link.Image != "1")
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(link.Image)" class="UsefullLink-icon" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="~/images/Logo200blue.png" class="UsefullLink-icon" />
                        }
                        <a href="@link.LinkUrl" class="justify-content-center" target="_blank"> @link.Name</a>

                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

after run project I got this error

> InvalidOperationException: Processing of the LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
> KeySelector: u.Name,
> ElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: UsefullLink
> ValueBufferExpression:
> ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
> IsNullable: False

***UPDATE1:***
and for group I have this in Univer.Business.Model

```
public class Group<k, T>
{
        public k Key;
        public IEnumerable<T> Values;
}
```

***Update2***
this is constructor for my Repository
public class UsefullLinkRepository : IUsefullLinkRepository
{
private readonly UniverContext _db;

```
    public UsefullLinkRepository(UniverContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
}
```

and I change it method to

```
var data = from b in _db.UsefullLinks.AsEnumerable()
                   join c in _db.UseFullLinkTypes on b.UseFullLinkTypeId equals c.Id
                   group b by b.UseFullLinkType.Name into g
                   select g;

        return data.Select(g => new Group<string, UsefullLink>
        {
            Key = g.Key,
            Values = g
        }).ToList();
```

After run ***Update2***
I got this error

> InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Comment: I would suggest to move Where closer to ToListAsync. It simplifies query translation a lot.

Comment: Could you please share detailed code about your model?What is your UsefullLink and UseFullLinkType?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and thanks for you help, after your help I got many Ideas, and I had many unknown think about that, another side I like Linq Lambda, I one of suggestion, I got that add **"MultipleActiveResultSets=true"** but I think I had not problem before upgrade my project, it mean this problem come from my query and in the next time if I want edit my another query, maybe I send many connection to database and it's not good for performance,
another thinks was that I use external class from business layer of my project, it was from .net core 2.2 and in .net core 5.0 I try to use better approach,
and the result was, I remove **"MultipleActiveResultSets=true"** from my connection string and cut use of group class from another layer of project, the final Query become in my repository :

```
  return _db.UsefullLinks
            .Join(_db.UseFullLinkTypes.AsEnumerable(),
                  ul => ul.UseFullLinkTypeId,
                  ult => ult.Id,
                  (ul, ult) => new { ul = ul, ult = ult }).AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(
            x=>x.ul.UseFullLinkType.Name,x=>x.ul )
            .Select (g=>g).ToList();
```

And in my View I had small change

```
@model List<IGrouping<string, Univer.Model.UsefullLink>>
@{
 ViewData["Title"] = "ServiceTebbedTable";
}

<div class="container">
<div class="row UsefullLink ">

    <div class="card ">
        <div class="card-header"> <a asp-action="ServiseTable" asp-controller="Home" asp-area="">Service Table</a></div>
        <ul class="row" style="margin-left:25px ;margin-right:25px;">

            @foreach (var group in Model)
            {
                <li class="row col-md-12" id="cut-diamond"> @group.Key</li>
                <li class="m-1"></li>
                foreach (var link in group)
                {

                    <li class="col-md-4 mt-2  justify-content-center">

                        @if (link.Image != "1")
                        {
                            <img src="@Url.Content(link.Image)" class="UsefullLink-icon" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <img src="~/images/Logo200blue.png" class="UsefullLink-icon" />
                        }
                        <a href="@link.LinkUrl" class="justify-content-center" target="_blank"> @link.Name</a>

                    </li>

                   
                }
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem here that EF 2.x silently evaluates non translatable query on the client side. It is a bug that EF Core 5 do not throw correct exception in this case.

Consider to rewrite your query

```cs
var grouped = from b in _db.UsefullLinks.AsEnumerable()
              group b by b.UseFullLinkType.Name into g
              select g;

return grouped.Select(g => new Univer.Business.Model.Group<string, UsefullLink> 
    { 
        Key = g.Key, 
        Values = g // this assignment is not translatable
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: after that I got this error 'Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.'

Comment: Sorry, corrected query. It was late, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Change like below:

```
var data = from b in _db.UsefullLinks.AsEnumerable()
                join c in _db.UseFullLinkType.AsEnumerable() on b.UseFullLinkTypeId equals c.Id
                group b by b.UseFullLinkType.Name into g
                select g;

return data.Select(g => new Group<string, UsefullLink>
{
    Key = g.Key,
    Values = g 
}).ToList();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time, as I know in Enumerable we don't send query to database, and we don't have open connection, as this scenario why I get this error: 'here is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

Comment: It could exactly work well in my .net 5 project.Could you please share your `_db` about how did you define the dbcontext?

Comment: It had worked fine before update, and there are many method that fetch data from database, Also I update my Question

Comment: Hi @sunny,try to make `MultipleActiveResultSets=true`.

Comment: Ok,I saw that in many answer, but is that a right way? before this which connection is open? Is it possible to lose control of connections with this method?

Comment: This can happen if you execute a query while iterating over the results from another query. It is not clear from your example where this happens because the example is not complete.One thing that can cause this is lazy loading triggered when iterating over the results of some query.If my answer helped you,please accept as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 return (from b in _db.UsefullLinks
            group b by b.UseFullLinkType.Name into g
            select new Univer.Business.Model.Group<string, UsefullLink> 
            { Key = g.Key, Values = g }).ToList();
```

Here, does UsefullLinks collection has 'Key' as a column? You may want to use g.Name instead of g.Key

Comment: I have a class that had 'Key', also I update my question

Comment: The Group<> class has 'Key'. But the 'g' collection above is of type UsefullLinks which does not have 'Key' property. Hence the question is whether 'g.Key' needs to be replaced with 'g.Name'??